# IText Image Set Absolute Position

Tags: java, android, itext

I need to position an image in a PDF using the iText library at the exact same position as shown in the screenshot below from Adobe Acrobat. What values do I need to pass to the image setabsolute position like so:

```
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        image.scaleAbsolute(150f, 150f);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(???f, ???f);

        PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
        overContent.addImage(image);
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
```

I am trying all the values and the image is jumping arround in the outputed file. What values should I use? I have also included the screenshot from the getFieldPosition() output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you porblem is you cant figure out the conversion of pt to an x,y location, maybe this will help:

> To go from Pixels to Em’s, simply divide by 16
>
> Use Reed Design’s table which lists conversions from Points to Pixels
>   to Em to %. It’s an approximation, which will depend on font, browser
>   and OS, but it’s a good starting point.

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070723201114AAzsYjC

Otherwise, I do something similar to yo for images:

```
    /**
     * Adds an image to the PDF
     * @param imageData The data for the image to add
     * @param page The page number of where to add the photo
     * @param xPos The x coordinate of where to put the image. Note that 0 is the left of the page
     * @param yPos The y coordinate of where to put the image. Note that 0 is the top of the page. This is
     * different than the addText function for some reason.
     * @param layer
     * @throws Exception If there was an error adding the image to the PDF
     */
    public void addImageToPDF(float xPos, float yPos, byte[] imageData, int page,  Layer layer) throws Exception
    {
        PdfContentByte content = getPdfContentByte(page, layer);
        Image img = Image.getInstance(imageData);
        img.setAbsolutePosition(xPos, yPos);
        content.addImage(img);
    }


    /**
     * Gets a PdfContentByte. This is used to make changes to the PDF
     * @param page The page number that is to be modified
     * @param layer The layer that is to be modified
     * @return A PdfContentByte that can be used to modify the PDF
     */
    private PdfContentByte getPdfContentByte(int page, Layer layer)
    {
        return layer == Layer.OVER ? stamper.getOverContent(page) : stamper.getUnderContent(page);
    }
```

Where Layer is a simple enum for determining what layer of the PDF something should go:

```
    /**
     * Represents a layer of the PDF relative to the original file. For example,
     * if an operation requires a Layer argument, OVER will make the changes ontop
     * of the original PDF. UNDER will make the changes under the original PDF. So
     * if there is text in the original PDF and you choose UNDER, the changes you make
     * may be covered up by the original text. If you choose OVER, you changes will be
     * ontop of whatever was in the original PDF
     */
    public enum Layer{
        /**
         * Represents ontop of the original PDF
         */
        OVER,

        /**
         * Represents under the original PDF
         */
        UNDER
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful response. For this document, I do not have an instance of a document, rather, I have an instance of a PdfStamper. And I get a reference of all the fields (AcroFields) in a form. One of those fields is a place holder textbox, what I want to do is to add an image to exactly the position of that textbox and then remove the textbox. I have made a lot of progress with this and I will continue to work on it. Thanks